# Bibtex error, citation not showing up

Tags: bibtex, winedt

Well, I have the following structure in Winedt:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
{ 
\title{Some title \\}
\section{Example}
Give refernce to \cite{a2}.
\section{References}
\bibliographystyle{numeric}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

And the entry with label a2 is saved in ref.bib in the same directory as :

```
@article{a2,
title={CS},
author={Donoho, David L},
journal={IEEE Transactions on information theory},
volume={52},
number={4},
pages={1289--1306},
year={2006},
publisher={IEEE}
}
```

However i get an error :

```
 LaTeX Warning: Citation `a2' on page 1 undefined on input line 48
```

No compliling error in Bibtex but still i am getting this error repeatedly and the citation is a question mark.

Comment: Welcome, please show the BibTeX log file (`.blg`).

Comment: I get a complaint by BibTeX that no bibliographystyle is give. Once this is fixed, BibTeX complains that the entry does not end properly. You forgot the closing brace.

Comment: Hi, there is no .blg file in my case. There is a .bbl file though and its empty (0 bytes). As for the brace, sorry, my mistake. The closing brace is there. But i made a typo.

Comment: BibTeX definitely can't do its job if it's not told which bibliography style should be employed.

Comment: Incidentally, `WinEdt` is just the "front end" -- it's not related to the problem you're looking to solve.

Comment: Added a command : \bibliographystyle{numeric} should solve the style issue i guess. But still the same.

Comment: `numeric` is not the name of an existing bibliography style file. You should be getting a BibTeX error message to this effect. I suggest you use `IEEEtran` and rerun LaTeX , BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Comment: Hi, used acm instead of numeric and references showed up ! Thanks Mico and Johannes_B for pinpointing the exact issue.

Comment: Yes, IEEtran will be the exact style.

Comment: It's `IEEEtran`, not `IEEtran`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most importantly, you need to select a valid bibliography style. Since you're using the `IEEEtran` document class, you probably can't too wrong if you select `IEEEtran` as the bibliography style.

If you end up using the `IEEEtran` bibliography style, be sure to provide all fields customarily shown in IEEEtran journals. In the example code you posted, the `month` field is missing.

By the way, the preamble of your document is needlessly complex and cluttered, For instance, some of the packages you load are automatically loaded by other packages. By not loading `amsfonts`, `caption`, and `array` separately, you'll make the preamble a lot easier to read -- and debug, if ever needed.

A separate issue: the `hyperref` package should generally (with only a few exceptions) be loaded last. See also the comments in the code below.

A final comment: The issue you've encountered -- the missing `\bibliographystyle` directive -- is wholly unrelated to WinEd, or any other front-end.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@article{a2,
title  = {Compressed Sensing},
author = {Donoho, David L.},
journal= {IEEE Transactions on Information Theory},
volume = {52},
number = {4},
pages  = {1289-1306},
year   = {2006},
month  = {April},
publisher={IEEE},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} % <-- or: "plain"
%%%%\usepackage{caption} % is loaded by 'subcaption'
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}%%%%,amsfonts
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%%%%\usepackage{array} % is loaded by 'tabularx'
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref} % <--- should be loaded last

\begin{document}
%%%%{ 
%%%%\title{Some title} %%%%\\ % not needed for the MWE
\section{Example}
Give reference to \cite{a2}.
%%%%\section{References} % <-- not needed
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @mrin9san - You're most welcome!